# Telerik grid columns change size when using inline editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik grid which uses inline editing.

Something I found it does which is quite annoying is when I start editing a row some of the columns resizes, the delete button dissapears and a 'cancel' button appears next to the edit button in the edit buttons column.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is how the grid is being created:

```
<%
Html.Telerik().Grid<myapp.Date>("dates")
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.id))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
    {
        dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Dates")
        .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Dates")
        .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Dates")
        .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Dates");
    })
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.name);
        columns.Bound(o => o.date1);
        columns.Command(commands => commands.Edit());
        columns.Command(commands=> commands.Delete());
    })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Render();
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the normal way how Telerik Grid behaves.

You can make those columns hidden, if don't need them.

Or may be you can try to use InCell edit mode.